# How do I force an element in my DIV to take up as much horizontal space as possible?

Tags: html, css, width, css-tables

I have a DIV with two elements in it, that I want on the same horizontal plane (assuming there is enough screen real estate).  The left element is a table and the right element is a fixed width sag element.

```
<div id="content">

<table id="currencyTable">
...
</table>

<div id="pieChart">
<svg width="700" height="400">
    <g id="labels" />
</svg>
</div>

</div>
```

How do I make the left element (the table) occupy all the unoccupied space that the fixed width pie chart hasn't taken up?  I thought setting the "width:100%" attribute would do it ...

```
#currencyContent {
    display: block;
}

#currencyTable {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #C7CDD1;
    width: 100%;
}

#pieChart {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: yellow;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

but the chart is still slipping below the horizontal plane of the table -- https://jsfiddle.net/t53agm0z/ .  How can I get both on the same line, but more importantly, make the table occupy as much horizontal space as the parent DIV allows?

Comment: The pie goes below because the table IS taking 100% - see the table's border. The fields in turn are not taking all the space in the table.

Comment: I dont' want the table to take 100% of the row, I want it to take 100% of whatever's left of the row after accounting for the space the pie chart is occupying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `display: inline-block;` from `#currencyTable`:

```
#content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#currencyTable {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #C7CDD1;
  width: calc(100% - 700px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #currencyTable {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

use media query to control the width. at >1200px `width: calc(100% - 750px);` at <= 1200px, table width set to 100%.

Also, add the following to align th text:

```
#currencyTable tr th {
  text-align: left;
}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/jzy0hjzg/

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height"),
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var labels = d3.select("#labels");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#98abc5",
  "#8a89a6",
  "#7b6888",
  "#6b486b",
  "#a05d56",
  "#d0743c",
  "#ff8c00",
  "#e34d01",
  "#ccff05",
  "#3e7eca",
  "#aa0092",
  "#b32e4f"
]);

var pie = d3.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.market_cap;
  });

var path = d3.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(0);

var label = d3.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 40)
  .innerRadius(radius - 40);

var csvData = "currency,market_cap\n";
csvData += "Ethereum,29414864581\n";
csvData += "Ripple,8134952806\n";
csvData += "Bitcoin Cash,8985112165\n";
csvData += "Litecoin,3711925522\n";
csvData += "NEM,2574666000\n";
csvData += "Dash,2450463008\n";
csvData += "IOTA,1795131838\n";
csvData += "Ethereum Classic,1563577380\n";
csvData += "NEO,1134820000\n";
csvData += "Monero,1762581233\n";
csvData += "Stratis,593527604\n";
csvData += "Bitcoin,72310587213\n";
var data = d3.csvParse(csvData);
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.market_cap = +d.market_cap;
  return d;
});

var arc = g.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");

arc.append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.data.currency);
  });

arc.append("text")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")";
  })
  .attr("dy", "0.35em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.data.currency;
  });

// Now we'll draw our label lines, etc.
enteringLabels = labels.selectAll(".label").data(data).enter();
labelGroups = enteringLabels.append("g").attr("class", "label");
labelGroups.append("circle").attr({
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  r: 2,
  fill: "#000",
  transform: function(d, i) {
    centroid = pied_arc.centroid(d);
    return "translate(" + pied_arc.centroid(d) + ")";
  },
  'class': "label-circle"
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#currencyTable {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #C7CDD1;
  width: calc(100% - 700px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #currencyTable {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#currencyTable tr th {
  text-align: left;
}

.currency-row img,
.currency-row .name {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.currency-row {
  min-height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C7CDD1;
}

.currency-row img,
.currency-row .name {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.currency-row td {
  padding: 12px 0 12px 0;
}

.currency-row td:first-child {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.currency-row td:last-child {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.currency-icon img {
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.currency-title {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 8px solid #f00;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

#pieChart {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.arc text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">

  <table id="currencyTable" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Currency</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>1d Change</th>
      <th>1w Change</th>
      <th>1y Change</th>
      <th>% Index Market Cap</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even currency-row">
      <td>Bitcoin</td>
      <td>2731.8 USD</td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div> -1513.8 </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div> -1834.19 </td>
      <td>n/a</td>
      <td>53.79 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd currency-row">
      <td>Ethereum</td>
      <td>296.55 USD</td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div> -4.34 </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div> -70.49 </td>
      <td>n/a</td>
      <td>21.88 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even currency-row">
      <td>Monero</td>
      <td>46.78 USD</td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div> -61.21 </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div> -86.95 </td>
      <td>n/a</td>
      <td>1.31 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd currency-row">
      <td>Stratis</td>
      <td>5.83 USD</td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-up"></div> + 0.04 </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div> -1.05 </td>
      <td>n/a</td>
      <td>0.44 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even currency-row">
      <td>Ethereum Classic</td>
      <td>13.66 USD</td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div> -2.54 </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div> -2.14 </td>
      <td>n/a</td>
      <td>1.16 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd currency-row">
      <td>NEM</td>
      <td>0.25 USD</td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div> -0.02 </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div> -0.04 </td>
      <td>n/a</td>
      <td>1.92 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even currency-row">
      <td>NEO</td>
      <td>17.09 USD</td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-up"></div> + 6.39 </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-up"></div> + 0.18 </td>
      <td>n/a</td>
      <td>0.84 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd currency-row">
      <td>Bitcoin Cash</td>
      <td>591.32 USD</td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-up"></div> + 64.16 </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-up"></div> + 30.21 </td>
      <td>n/a</td>
      <td>6.68 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even currency-row">
      <td>Ripple</td>
      <td>0.09 USD</td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-up"></div> + 0.01 </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-up"></div> + 0.01 </td>
      <td>n/a</td>
      <td>6.05 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd currency-row">
      <td>Litecoin</td>
      <td>65.41 USD</td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div> -0.48 </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-up"></div> + 2.82 </td>
      <td>n/a</td>
      <td>2.76 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even currency-row">
      <td>Dash</td>
      <td>370.17 USD</td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-up"></div> + 55.46 </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-up"></div> + 8.79 </td>
      <td>n/a</td>
      <td>1.82 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd currency-row">
      <td>IOTA</td>
      <td>0.51 USD</td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div> -0.16 </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div> -0.32 </td>
      <td>n/a</td>
      <td>1.34 %</td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <div id="pieChart">
    <svg width="700" height="400">
      <g id="labels" />
    </svg>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey even if I run your snippet, its not working.  THe pie chart is always appearing beneath the table.  I want them to appear alongside one another, and have the table occupy as much width as possible.  Ditto for your fiddle, even when I expand it as far as it can go.

Comment: No, what I said was "How do I make the left element (the table) occupy all the unoccupied space that the fixed width pie chart hasn't taken up?".  I do want both elements to stay on the same horizontal plane, if possible.

Comment: @Dave ok check it now

Comment: Cool.  Couple fo questions -- my pie chart is hard-coded at 700px, but one of your CSS rules uses "750" ( "width: calc(100% - 750px);" ).  Was that just an oversight or is there a reason to use 50 extra pixels?  (You don't have to edit your question if it was an oversight)

Comment: @Dave the thing is your `border: 1px solid #C7CDD1;` does not count as the width, therefore you need to do 100% - 702px, but if you add `box-sizing: border-box;` then border will count into the width, then you can use  100% - 700px. check the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand right what you need, you can use a few variants:
1. absolute position chart wrapper block. e.g.

```
// CSS
#content{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}

#currencyTable {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #C7CDD1;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 100px; // 100px Fixed width of chart
}

#pieChart {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
// HTML
<div id="pieChart">
  <svg width="100" height="400"> // 100px Fixed width if chart
    <g id="labels" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/bxtmrd59/

2. Use `display: table-row, table-cell` for table and chart, like

   ```
   #content{
       position: relative;
       display: table-row;
   }

   #currencyTable {
       background-color: #ffffff;
       border: 1px solid #C7CDD1;
       display: table-cell;
   }

   #pieChart {
       display: table-cell;
       background-color: yellow;
       vertical-align: top;
   }
   ```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/temz10fp/1/

3 Use flexbox, like:

```
#content{
  display: flex;
}

#currencyTable {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #C7CDD1;
    display:  flex-grow: 1;
 }

#pieChart {
    background-color: yellow;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
}
```

example https://jsfiddle.net/j0ggskbv/1/

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using div-table as follows:

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/corix010/rse4dumh/).

CSS:

```
    .div-table{display:table; border:1px solid #003399;}
    .div-table-row{display:table-row;}
    .div-table-col{display:table-cell; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #003399;}
    * {-moz-box-sizing: border-box;}

    #currencyTable {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #pieChart {
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
  <div id = "content" class="div-table" style="width:100%">
    <div class="div-table-row">
      <div class="div-table-col">
        <table id="currencyTable">
            <tr>
                <th>Currency</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>1d Change</th>
                <th>1w Change</th>
                <th>1y Change</th>
                <th>% Index Market Cap</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even currency-row">
                <td>Bitcoin</td>
                <td>2731.8 USD</td>
                <td><div class="arrow-down"></div>  -1513.8 </td>
                <td><div class="arrow-down"></div>  -1834.19 </td>
                <td>n/a</td>
                <td>53.79 %</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="pieChart" class="div-table-col">
        Your piechart
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does that work for you?  Its not working for me applying it to the Fiddle I posted.

Comment: @Dave as soon as I decrease the width of the JSFiddle left panel which increases the right panel so that the two elements inside the div could both fit, it seems to work for me.

Comment: THere may be some confusion about what I want.  I don't want the table to take up 100% of the row, I want the table and the pie chart to take up 100% of the row.

Answer (score -1):

Use

> width: 100%

Also, if you have any padding or margin then use

> padding: 0 auto;
>
> margin: 0 auto;